# How to organize controllers with 2 user models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The current setup I have now is fresh and just installed Devise, and created 2 models. One called User and the other called Admin.

The question I have is that they both share some elements. Say like notifications. Whilst some are only to one of the models. In the past I have been taking the easy way out and not properly organizing them properly.

How do I structure the controllers so that they are up to date with proper standards?

Answer (score 0):

If you have same relations on `User` and `AdminUser` it's because your `AdminUser` it's a system user too. Am I wrong? if this is the case, I would remove `ActiveAdmin` model adding on `User` model a role attribute. I think [this](http://renisoft.com/devise-activeadmin-cancan-single-user-model/) is what you need to do.